# Middleware is not working properly in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-middleware, laravel-authentication

I have an admin panel in my Laravel project.

There have a `login page` and a `dashboard page`.
While user successfully login, application takes user to the dashboard page.

But from when I add my custom `middleware` to my `route` for checking the user authentication, though I have given correct email and password for logging, application all time take me to the login page instead of taking me to `dashboard page`.

**userController.php**

```
public function admin_login(Request $request)
{
    $rules = [
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ];

    $customMessages = [
        'email.required' => 'Email Required',
        'password.required' => 'Password Required'
    ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);

    if (!User::where('username', '=', $request->email)->exists()) {

        Session::flash('message', 'You are not an Admin!'); 
        Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-danger'); 
        return back();
    }

    if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password]))
    {
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }

    Session::flash('message', 'Password is Incorrect!'); 
    Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-info'); 
    return back();
}
```

**dashboardController.php**

```
public function index()
{
     return view('admin.dashboard.dashboard');
}
```

**adminAuthenticate middleware**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!Auth::check()) {
            return redirect()->route('login_page');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

I have added my custom middleware into **kernel.php**

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/admin-login', 'userController@index')->name('login_page');
Route::get('/dashboard', 'dashboardController@index')->middleware('adminAuth');
```

**kernel.php**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'adminAuth' => \App\Http\Middleware\adminAuthenticate::class, //custom middleware
    ];
```

Can't understand where is the problem. Anybody Help Please ? Thanks in advance

Comment: can u show your kernel.php ??

Comment: @user11622164......   updated post

Comment: @NicoHaase....I have use `dd()` in the middleware for checking the user activation....that result is ok...user activation shows null while logout...but don't redirect to the route...

Comment: You expect to run return redirect('/dashboard'); after user login right? you can dd just before this line, maybe it never go into this condition, also check did you inherit Middleware\Authenticate::class, because there has a checking if user is not logon, redirect to lgin page.

Comment: @Momo....the piquiliar thing is if I remove the `middleware('adminAuth');` from the `/dashboard` route...then dashboard page is coming after successfully login.....

Answer (score 0):

After I'm reviewing your code. I saw the user controller wrong condition.

```
if (!User::where('username', '=', $request->email)->exists()) {

   Session::flash('message', 'You are not an Admin!'); 
   Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-danger'); 
   return back();
}
```

You input email, But your condition compares with the username, So authenticate will false.
I hope that can help you. Thanks!

Comment: Value is email in DB 'username' data field....so no problem with authentication